# How do cell signaling ensures time synchronization?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-signaling

Let us suppose two cells **A** and **B** communicating with one another, I want to know how do cells ensure time synchronization while communicating. For instance, let us assume cell **A** sends a sequence '110'. Where '1' corresponds to dissemination of certain number of molecules, while '0' corresponds to no transmission of molecules. Now, cell **B** detects first '1', and then because of some delay in the reception of another '1', the sequence now received is '101'.
I want to know that how do cells ensure time synchronization?

Or because of very small distances over communication range, there is no need of it?

Comment: As far as I know, cells don't detect sequences like you're proposing (though of course, there could be exceptions). While cells can detect changes in signal over time, it's not as straightforward as on/off, and this is generally modeled in analog terms via complex sets of differential equations.

Comment: Look at, e.g. http://science.sciencemag.org/content/298/5596/1241 for some examples of how cells can respond to transient signals of different lengths

Comment: Maybe the more robust option for sending signals like "111" vs "110" is combinatorial regulation - multiple different types of molecules, so information is conveyed by seeing whether molecule X is high AND molecule Y is high, etc.

Comment: Sorry! But I can't understand your last comment, do you want to say that some type of AND gate is used here to doubly ensure the proper detection.